# Capybara checkbox not triggering JS?

Tags: capybara, rspec-rails

I am trying to test the following form which allows a user to hide their profile by checking a checkbox.

```
<%= form_tag toggle_hidden_path, id: 'toggle-form', method: :put, remote: true do %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:hide, value = '1', checked = @account_is_hidden) %>
<% end %>
```

When checked or unchecked (changed), the form is submitted using JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#hide').on('change', function() { $(this.form).submit(); });
</script>
```

My controller action and method within the model toggle the :hidden boolean.

```
  # accountsController

  def toggle_hidden
    @account = current_user.account
    @account.toggle_hidden!
  end

  # account.rb

  def toggle_hidden!
   toggle!(:hidden)
  end
```

I am using Rspec and capybara. My test is below

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Hide and show profile' do
  let(:account) {create :account}

  scenario 'successfully', js: true do
    login_as(account.user)
    visit dashboard_path

    expect(account.hidden).to eq(false)

    expect(page).to have_field('hide')
    check('hide')
    expect(page).to have_field('hide', checked: true)

    expect(account.hidden).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

The test error;

```
Failures:

1) Hide and show profile successfully
 Failure/Error: expect(account.hidden).to eq(true)

   expected: true
        got: false

   (compared using ==)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as to why this may not be working..

**EDIT**

I added a flash notice to display when the checkbox is checked/unchecked.

```
  def toggle_hidden
   @account = current_user.account
   @account.toggle_hidden!
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js { flash[:notice] = "Hidden toggled" }
    end
  end
```

and updated the spec - but still, test does not pass.

```
expect(page).to have_content('Hidden toggled')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already loaded `account` so the value of `hidden` in the object won't change.  In order to see the new value you'd need to reload the object

```
expect(account.reload.hidden).to eq(true)
```

However, since actions (check/uncheck/click/etc) aren't guaranteed to wait for any behaviors triggered by them it's highly likely the form submission won't have completed (and hence the object not been updated) by the time your expectation runs (hence why expectations on database objects are generally frowned upon in feature specs).  If your page has a visible change when the form submit is completed you should set an expectation on that before checking the database object, or better yet just skip testing the database object and instead test what the user can actually see - that their profile is hidden after they've checked the box.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for your input. I've added a flash notice to appear when the checkbox is checked, and an expectation that the page has that content however still no luck. i've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @RailsJohn -- is the new expectation failing? Or that passes, and the old one still fails?  If it is the old one still failing, make sure you have added the `reload` to the call so you're not checking the old value.  If the new one is failing, add the exact error message you are getting to the question.  Oh -- and you probably want to be setting `flash.now[:notice]` rather than `flash[:notice]` since you need it set immediately for the JS rendered response

Comment: I initially tried your first suggestion -expect(account.reload.hidden).to eq(true) which did not pass. Then implemented the flash notice (with and without .now) which still did not pass. It seems the form is not being submitted when the checkbox is checked, therefore the flash does not display, nor is the record updated.

Comment: @RailsJohn You should be able to tell if the form is actually being submitted by checking your `test.log` to see if the request is there.  Btw - which JS capable driver are you using with Capybara?  Also, I'm confused that the error message "expect(escort.account.hidden).to eq(true)" doesn't actually match your stated test "expect(account.hidden).to eq(true)" - are you sure the error is where you think it is?

Comment: Ah, I've just checked the logs. The form is not submitting. In order to isolate the issue, in the test I have confirmed the checkbox is on the page, I check it, then i confirm that the checkbox is checked on the page.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this was a typo - "expect(escort.account.hidden)".

Comment: I am using capybara webkit which I thought may be the issue but it is working fine elsewhere. I have a smoke test to simply check the index for JS errors. Errors are found when I have js: true but are not when I remove js: true. To me this indicates webkit is working. So ultimately the issue remains, when the checkbox is checked, the JS is not being triggered and therefore the form is not submitted.

Comment: I also changed the selector in the JS to the form ID rather than 'this.form' in desperation but no difference.

Comment: @RailsJohn So if the form isn't actually being submitted, then it's an issue with the JS/event handler.  Is the JS you show the entire script element used to trigger the submit, or did you extract that from a larger script?  capybara-webkit only supports at most ES5 (less if you built it with QtWebkit < 5.5) so if it was a bigger script element it's possible an error is preventing the handler from being attached.  Also, are you sure the checkbox isn't checked before you attempt to check it?  `expect(page).to have_unchecked_field('hide')` before calling 'check('hide')`

Comment: fixed it. I moved the JS into the view and it worked perfectly. I previously had the JS in app.js. Not sure why it was not working when that was the case but at least I have the test passing and can refactor from there. expect(account.reload.hidden).to eq(true) is now passing as you suggested. Thank you for your help. I didn't know you could run the test log so that is a big positive to come from this. Thank you also for you general contributions to factoryGirl and Capybara.

Comment: @RailsJohn that would imply your app.js has an error or is using ES 5.1+ features/methods that aren’t compatible with capybara-webkit